# Joomla not showing drop down menu anymore

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I was just recently adding some new pages to my Shared Services section. I added 3 new pages and when I went to go link to them on the navigation bar, my Workplace drop down menu now shows as a bulleted list instead. What could be the cause of this? I haven't touched that menu section since I finished it. I am using the JSN Epic PRO template style.

Comment: `#element li { list-style: none; }` << This will remove the bullets. Add it to your CSS file and change `#element` to whatever suits your needs

Comment: I havent had to touch the CSS file though. That's the thing. Even though it is a part of the same module it's acting like it is separate from all the other ones.

Comment: Hmm well without seeing a live preview it's kinda of hard to tell. We're either going to need to view the site to inspect it or you're going to have to contact the developer of the template